# Creating Oracle APEX Restful Services that returns XML and JSON

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a Restful service that will return JSON or XML data. The company is using Oracle application express (Restful Services) as the tool for the job.

I've noticed that the latest versions of Application Express the XML option is no longer.?

I was wondering does anyone one have any examples or ideas on how I can can create a Restful service that will return JSON or XML depending on the content type I request ?

I'm currently running Application Express 4.2.5.00.08.

This has always been pretty straight forward in other languages but I need to work it out with oracle data services [ORDS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/overview/index.html)

The current setup I have tried is to define a Restful service as follows ;

Resful Service Module :

```
  URI Template : test
  Method       : GET
  Source       : Query   Format  : JSON   (XML is no longer option)
  Require Secure Access : NO
```

Source :

```
SELECT RESTful_Testing.GetSampleData(:contentType) FROM DUAL
```

Parameters

```
Name               : Accept
Bind Variable Name : contentType
Access Method      : IN
Source Type        : HTTP Header
Parameter Type     : String
```

I have set it up so I can call an Oracle Package and pass in the content type. The problem I have is that the format is already predefined, so any attempt to return XML would be incorrect ( or can I alter the header later).

The Package Code is Very basic and is as follows just for testing ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE APEX_EDS.RESTful_Testing AS 

    TYPE resultCursor IS REF CURSOR;

    function GetSampleData(contentType VARCHAR) return resultCursor;

END RESTful_Testing;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY APEX_EDS.RESTful_Testing AS 

    function GetSampleData(contentType VARCHAR) return resultCursor AS
        O_resultCursor  resultCursor;

        BEGIN
            -- Check the Content Type
            IF ( contentType = 'application/xml' ) THEN
                OPEN O_resultCursor FOR
                select '<ROOT><NAME>John</NAME><SURNAME>Smith</SURNAME>   
                <CONTENT_TYPE>application/xml</CONTENT_TYPE></ROOT>' FROM DUAL;
                return(O_resultCursor);
            ELSE -- Assume JSON so return normal
                OPEN O_resultCursor FOR
                select 'John' FirstName, 'Smith' Surname, contentType ContentType FROM DUAL;
                return(O_resultCursor);
            END IF;
        END;   
END RESTful_Testing;
```

Hope that further adds to my issue and hope there are some oracle ORDS experts out there :).

Answer (score 0):

We are currently doing this on a project with apex. You should be able to find lots of tutorials online. E.g. http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r42/RESTful_WS_oll/RESTful_WS_oll.html

You can change the type of rest service to return JSON in the example above, but not XML. However it's fairly straightforward with the various xml functions in sql e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb13gen.htm#i1029583

I'm sure if you can get your restful services hooked up you should also be able to create a service to return a custom result which you can get from an xml query.

Comment: Hi kayakpim, Appreciate the answer. I have already followed the example tutorial and all is great returning JSON, I can return XML like you say by writing custom PLSQL to use XML functions but was really wondering why th eoption had been removed in this version of ORDS.

I'm more after an example of how with ORDS i can read in the request headers and depending on the type requested alter the output.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I get is by trying to manually set the output. I determine the content type to be returned from looking what the accept header is being sent by the request.

```
begin
  IF (:contentType = 'application/xml') THEN
    --set the response format
    owa_util.mime_header('application/xml', true, 'ISO-8859-4');
    htp.p('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>');
    htp.p('<ROOT>');
    htp.p('<NAME>');
    htp.p('JOHN');
    htp.p('</NAME>');
    htp.p('<SURNAME>');
    htp.p('SMITH');
    htp.p('</SURNAME>');
    htp.p('<CONTENT_TYPE>');
    htp.p(:contentType);
    htp.p('</CONTENT_TYPE>');
    htp.p('</ROOT>');
 ELSE
   owa_util.mime_header('application/json', true);
   --quick json here will need to use library to parse query       
   -- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson/ used for real data
   htp.p('{"name" : "John" , "surname" : "smith", "content_type" : ' || :contentType || '}');
 END IF;
end;
```

It shows that it can be done but I still would like to here from people out there if there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks

Neil

Comment: Rather than htp.p the output manually you should be able to do an xml sql query to get the xmltype object (or a string version of it) and just output that. Maybe someone else can explain why the xml option was removed.

Comment: Yep I will use XML Query , just wanted to try and solve how I could return the two types , thanks for feedback. I'm going to contact oracle through our support account and Ill update this post if I find why the XML option is no longer. cheers